# Want to have button control for panorama navigation

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I need to have a button for forward and backward navigation for panorama controls instead of touch dragging.Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is **possible using the changing the PanoramaControlName.SelectedIndex** Property upon the click on the forward and backward button click.

Comment: Can you plz give me an example